# Formula for When Status Gets Changed to Specific Values

Tags: formula

I am trying to create a WFR formula that will set a date/time when statuses are moved into specific statuses on the case. Can someone help with how to format this so when ever any one of the statuses below are selected the rule will fire?

```
AND(
ISCHANGED( Status ),
ISPICKVAL(Status, "Processed"),
ISPICKVAL(Status, "Additional Processing In Progress ")
ISPICKVAL(Status, "Employer Verification Pending")
ISPICKVAL(Status, "Hearing Scheduled")
))
```

Comment: Remember `Status` cannot simultaneously be two different values. Your current rule looks for such a scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need a nested `OR` to pick up on any one of the statuses, along with the change to that field:

```
AND( ISCHANGED( Status ), 
     OR(ISPICKVAL(Status, "Processed"), 
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Additional Processing In Progress "),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Employer Verification Pending"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Hearing Scheduled")))
```